# Using async function Promise return value in Uppy initialization

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, uppy

I am trying to attach a JWT token from AWS Cognito to Uppy requests in my upload component. To get the token, I believe I need an async function:

```
async function getSessionToken() {
  const data = (await Auth.currentSession()).getAccessToken().getJwtToken()
  console.log(data)

  return data;
}
```

Then I use this return value in the actual function component:

```
export default function UppyUpload () {
  
  const data = getSessionToken();
  
  const uppy = useUppy(() => {
    return new Uppy({
      debug: true,
      autoProceed: false,
      restrictions: {
        maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
        minNumberOfFiles: 1,
        allowedFileTypes: ['video/*'],
        requiredMetaFields: ['caption'],
      }
    })
    .use(AwsS3Multipart, {
      limit: 4,
      companionUrl: 'http://localhost:3020/',
      companionHeaders: {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + data,
        'uppy-auth-token': "Bearer " + data,
      }
    })
...
```

However, `data` inside `UppyUpload` returns a promise, as anticipated. But I need this to resolve into a value somehow because I think the Uppy initialization requires this value (`Authorization': "Bearer " + data`) at the time of function rendering.

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue, but I feel like this is probably a common problem. Is there a recommended way?

Comment: `const data = await getSessionToken();`

Comment: Don't all `await` statements have to be within an `async` function? The function component `UppyUpload` isn't an async function though?

Comment: use `getUploadParameters` option for `AwsS3`

Comment: Using S3Multipart, not S3. Edited original post

Answer (score 0):

await should be used outside the function

```
async function getSessionToken() {
      const data = await (Auth.currentSession()).getAccessToken().getJwtToken()
      console.log(data)
    
      return data;
    }
```

Comment: That would still return a promise, no?

Comment: How could you use method under method await is a js method